# How to clear the value of a sum after a given number of iterations?

Tags: c

Please pardon the wording as I am struggling to describe the issue properly.

I am working on a program to create monthly rainfall summaries across a number of years. Right now the program loops through 12 months over 5 years and will print the results.

Unfortunately I am not able to figure out how to properly calculate the yearly totals. For example: If I input 1 for the first 12 values (i.e. Year 1) then the total is 12. If I do the same for Year 2 then the total becomes 24. It -looks- as though it is printing the sum of values from all years and not just the sum WITHIN a year.

This is a summarized version of what I am seeing:

```
Do you want to input Precipitation data? (y for yes)
y
Enter rain for 1, 1:
1
Enter rain for 1, 2:
1
... 
1
Enter rain for 1, 11:
1
Enter rain for 1, 12:
1
Total rainfall: 12.00   
Enter rain for 2, 1:
1
Enter rain for 2, 2:
1
...
Enter rain for 2, 12:
1
Total rainfall: 24.00
```

When I tried building a separate loop such as the one below the values are always 0.00:

```
void inputdata() {
    /* variable definition: */
    float Rain = 1.0;
    float total = 0.0;

    // Input Data
    for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
      for (int month = 0; month < NUMMONTHS; month++) {
        printf("Enter rain for %d, %d:\n", year + 1, month + 1);
        scanf("%f", & Rain);
        Raindata[year][month] = Rain;
      }
      printf("Total rainfall: %.2f\t\n", total);
    }
    for (int month = 0; month < NUMMONTHS; month++) {
        total = total + Rain;
    }
  }
```

The biggest frustration is that I can almost see how it is performing the math operations but just not how to fix them.

Here is my full code:

```
#define NUMMONTHS 12
#define NUMYEARS 5
#include <stdio.h>

// function prototypes
void inputdata();
void printdata();

// Global variables
// These are available to all functions
float Raindata[NUMYEARS][NUMMONTHS];
char years[NUMYEARS][5] = {
  "2011", "2012", "2013",
  "2014", "2015"
};
char months[NUMMONTHS][12] = {
  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr",
  "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug",
  "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
};

int main() {
    char enterData = 'y';
    printf("Do you want to input Precipatation data? (y for yes)\n");
    scanf("%c", & enterData);
    if (enterData == 'y') {
      // Call Function to Input data
      inputdata();
      // Call Function to display data
      printdata();
    } else {
      printf("No data was input at this time\n");
    }
    printf("Please try the Precipitation program again. \n");
    return 0;
  }

// function to inputdata
void inputdata() {
    /* variable definition: */
    float Rain = 1.0;
    float total = 0.0;

    // Input Data
    for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
      for (int month = 0; month < NUMMONTHS; month++) {
        printf("Enter rain for %d, %d:\n", year + 1, month + 1);
        scanf("%f", & Rain);
        Raindata[year][month] = Rain;
        total = total + Rain;
      }
      printf("Total rainfall: %.2f\t\n", total);
    }
  }

// Function to printdata
void printdata() {
  // Print data
  printf("year\t month\t rain\n");
  for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
    for (int month = 0; month < NUMMONTHS; month++) {

      printf("%s\t %s\t %5.2f\n", years[year], months[month], Raindata[year][month]);
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Your loop that calculates `Total` isn't adding the amounts from each month. It's just adding the last month `NUMMONTHS` times.

Comment: Why are you printing the total in the input function, not the print function?

Comment: Curious why 12 in `char months[NUMMONTHS][12]`?  Suggest `const char *months[NUMMONTHS] = {
  "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", ...};` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after you leave the inner loop, but inside the outer loop, reset the value of `Total` by setting it to `0`.

```
for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
  total = 0.0;
  for (int month = 0; month < NUMMONTHS; month++) {
    printf("Enter rain for %d, %d:\n", year + 1, month + 1);
    scanf("%f", & Rain);
    Raindata[year][month] = Rain;
    total = total + Rain;
  }
  printf("Total rainfall: %.2f\t\n", total);
}
```

This way, you start afresh from zero each year.

Comment: He wants to start afresh each year, to get the yearly totals.

Comment: @Barmar I seem to misunderstand - isn't that what I did?

Comment: Sorry, misread what you wrote.

Comment: Jeesus... I somewhat knew that I had to re-assign total = 0 somewhere but was obviously too blind to see.

Thanks for the inputs guys :)

Comment: @BanjoFox Look at it this way - each iteration of the outer loop represents a year, and each iteration of the inner loop represents a month in the particular year represented by the current iteration. You want to refresh each year. So you do it in the outer loop.

Comment: @GoodDeeds - That makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Calculate the total in `printdata()`, and set it to `0` at the beginning of each year.

```
void printdata() {
  // Print data
  printf("year\t month\t rain\n");
  for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
    float total = 0;
    for (int month = 0; month < NUMMONTHS; month++) {
      printf("%s\t %s\t %5.2f\n", years[year], months[month], Raindata[year][month]);
      total += Raindata[year][month];
    }
    printf("%s Total\t %6.2f\n", total);
  }
}
```

Comment: small typo on your 8th line: `Randata` should be `Raindata`.