# C Calculating annual rainfall totals with nested loops, & matching user inputs

Tags: c

I am having the hardest time understanding why my program won't execute correctly.  I need to calculate the total rainfall per year using a loop, the problem I'm having is its not excepting the user input for the month of February and instead adds the previous years total (i.e. 2011 total becomes Feb. 2012 user input).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define NUMMONTHS 12
#define NUMYEARS 5

// function prototypes
void inputdata();
void printdata();

// Global variables
// These are available to all functions
float Raindata[NUMYEARS][NUMMONTHS];
float sum = 0.0;
char years[NUMYEARS][5] = {"2011","2012","2013","2014","2015"};
char months[NUMMONTHS][12] =
   {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};

int main ()
{
    char enterData = 'y';
    printf("Do you want to input Precipatation data? (y for yes)\n");
    scanf("%c",&enterData);
    if (enterData == 'y') {
        // Call Function to Input data
        inputdata();

        // Call Function to display data
        printdata();
    }
    else {
        printf("No data was input at this time\n");
    }
    printf("Please try the Precipitation program again. \n");

    return 0;
}

// function to inputdata
void inputdata() {
    /* variable definition: */
    float Rain=1.0;
    // Input Data
    for (int year=0;year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
       for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
         printf("Enter rain for %d, %d:\n", year+1, month+1);
         scanf("%f",&Rain);
         Raindata[year][month]=Rain;
       }
    }
}

// Function to printdata
void printdata()
{
    // Print data
    printf ("year\t month\t rain\n");

    //Function to sum rainfall 
    for (int year=0; year< NUMYEARS; year++) {
        for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
              printf("%s\t %s\t %5.2f\n", 
                years[year],months[month],Raindata[year][month]);
             Raindata[year][NUMMONTHS+1] += Raindata[year][month]; 
        }
        printf("Total amount of rain for year %s: %5.2f\n", years[year], 
               Raindata[year][NUMMONTHS+1]); //prints the total amount of rain every year 
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Total amount of rain for year 2011: 40.00
2012     Jan      1.10
2012     Feb     40.00
2012     Mar      3.30
```

Comment: Raindata[year][NUMMONTHS+1] += Raindata[year][month]; AND Raindata[year][NUMMONTHS+1]);You gave the value exceeding the maximum limit of the array that is NUMMONTHS.

Comment: Note that although the lines `void inputdata();` — `void printdata();` declare the functions, they are _not_ prototypes.  To be prototypes, you'd need `void inputdata(void);` — `void printdata(void);`.

Comment: Akin to [How to clear the value of a sum after a given number of iterations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45062866/2410359).  Posted by user last seen 2 days ago, about when this user appeared.  Flagged

Comment: why is the header file: `stdio.h` included 3 times?

Comment: regarding: `float sum = 0.0;` This statement is initializing a `float` value from a `double` constant.  Perhaps you meant: `float sum = 0.0f;`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  I.E. `if( 1 != scanf("%c ",&enterData) ) { // handle error and exit }  // implied else, scanf successful`  The trailing space to consume the newline

Comment: regarding this line: `if (enterData == 'y')`  1) always place the literal on the left, so a keypunch error like: `if ( 'y' = enterData )` will be caught by the compiler.  Suggest also allowing `'Y'`

Comment: regarding: `float Rain=1.0;`  note my earlier comment about using a `double` to initialize a `float`.

Comment: this line: `printf("Enter rain for %d, %d:\n", year+1, month+1);` outputs `Enter rain for 1, 1` which is not really informative.  Suggest: `printf("Enter rain for %s, %s:\n", years[year], months[month]);`

Comment: this line: `Raindata[year][NUMMONTHS+1] += Raindata[year][month];`  is writing beyond the end of the columns in each row of the array `Raindata[][]`   Since a 2 dimensional array is kept in memory in consecutive  memory locations, the first year is writing into the second month of the second year (and so on for each year).   This also means that the final year is writing into memory beyond the end of the array `Raindata[][]`.   Both of these errors result in undefined behavior and the second error can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: In C, array indexes are from 0 to number of elements in array -1.  So using the number of elements in array as an index is accessing beyond the bounds of the array.  This results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you're trying to store the total for each year in a variable that doesn't exist - an extra array element `Raindata[year][month+1]`.  You only declared a 5x12 array, and you're trying to use it as a 5x13.  Because of the way the array is stored in memory, you are storing the `[month+1]` value in the next year's data.

Instead, I've added an extra array (`RainTotal[NUMYEARS]`), and used that to store your total for each year.

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define NUMMONTHS 12
#define NUMYEARS 5


// function prototypes
void inputdata(void);
void printdata(void);


// Global variables
// These are available to all functions
float Raindata[NUMYEARS][NUMMONTHS];
float RainTotal[NUMYEARS];
float sum = 0.0;
char years[NUMYEARS][5] = {"2011","2012","2013","2014","2015"};
char months[NUMMONTHS][4] =
  {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};

int main ()
  {
    char enterData = 'y';
    printf("Do you want to input Precipatation data? (y for yes)\n");
    scanf("%c",&enterData);

    if (enterData == 'y') {
      // Call Function to Input data
      inputdata();


      // Call Function to display data
      printdata();
    }
    else {
      printf("No data was input at this time\n");
    }

    printf("Please try the Precipitation program again. \n");

    return 0;
  }

// function to inputdata
void inputdata() {
  // variable definition
  float Rain=1.0;
  // Input Data
  for (int year=0;year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
    for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
      printf("Enter rain for %s, %s:\n", years[year], months[month]);
      scanf("%f",&Rain);
      Raindata[year][month]=Rain;
    }
  }
}

// Function to printdata
void printdata() {
  // Print data
  printf ("year\t month\t rain\n");

  //Function to sum rainfall
  for (int year=0; year< NUMYEARS; year++) {
    for (int month=0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
      printf("%s\t %s\t %5.2f\n",
        years[year],months[month],Raindata[year][month]);
        RainTotal[year] += Raindata[year][month];
    }
    printf("Total amount of rain for year %s: %5.2f\n", years[year],
      RainTotal[year]); //prints the total amount of rain every year
  }
}
```

I've also made some other changes:

- You declared `years` and `months` with a second array element seemingly equal to number of years, and number of months.  Instead, it should be the expected length of the `char` string, plus 1 (for the null terminator).
- I changed your printing statement to show the character strings that you declared, so `Enter rain for 2011, Jan:` instead of `Enter rain for 1, 1:`
- I fixed your function prototypes (also pointed out by another user)
- Cleaned up your formatting - have a look at some popular coding standards - this will make your code a LOT more readable when you're asking people to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMMONTHS 12
#define NUMYEARS 5

// function prototypes
void inputdata();
void printdata();

// global variables
float RaindataTotal[NUMYEARS];
float Raindata[NUMYEARS][NUMMONTHS];
float sum = 0.0;
char years[NUMYEARS][5] = { "2011","2012","2013","2014","2015" };
char months[NUMMONTHS][12] = { "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec" };

int main() {
    char enterData;

    while (1) {
        printf("Do you want to input Precipatation data? (y for yes)\n");
        scanf("%c", &enterData);

        if (enterData == 'y') {
            inputdata();
            printdata();
        }
        else if (enterData == 'n') {
            printf("No data was input at this time\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


// function to inputdata
void inputdata() {
    float Rain = 1.0;
    for (int year = 0; year < NUMYEARS; year++) {
        for (int month = 0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
            printf("Enter rain for %s, %s:\n", years[year], months[month]);
            scanf("%f", &Rain);
            Raindata[year][month] = Rain;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// Function to printdata
void printdata() {
    printf("year\t month\t rain\n");

    //Function to sum rainfall 
    for (int year = 0; year< NUMYEARS; year++) {
        for (int month = 0; month< NUMMONTHS; month++) {
            printf("%s\t %s\t %5.2f\n", years[year], months[month], Raindata[year][month]);
            RaindataTotal[year] += Raindata[year][month]; 
        }
        printf("Total amount of rain for year %s: %5.2f\n\n", years[year], RaindataTotal[year]); //prints the total amount  ??? of rain every year 
    }
}
```

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  1) `int main( void )` and 2) `int main( int char ** )`  While many compilers will allow `int main()` that is not a correct signature.

Comment: the prototypes for the sub functions are saying that the sub functions can have any number of parameters (including none); but that is not what should be used.  Suggest: `void inputdata( void );` and `void printdata( void );` so the compiler will not be allowing any parameters.

Comment: this statement, in the second (and following even numbered) iterations through the `while()` loop will be inputting '\n' rather than a user input.  To avoid this problem suggest using: `scanf(" %c", &enterData);`  Notice the space before the '%c' to consume any leading white space.

Comment: the second index in these statements: `char years[NUMYEARS][5] = { "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015" };` and `char months[NUMMONTHS][12] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar","Apr", "May","Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" }; is the number of items in the arrays and NOT the needed length of each item.   (also note how I've added a space after each comma, for readability.)  The C compiler can calculate the value for you, so suggest the second index be '[]'
`

Comment: @user3629249 , paste my code on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler then klik run

Comment: That online debugger is NOT exposing all the error/warning messages.  Strongly suggest compiling it your self, if using `gcc`, then use options: `-ggdb -Wall -Wextra  -Wconversion -std=gnu11 -pedantic -Wmissing-prototypes  -c`